# Cant get my trigger to work

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TRIGGER noOfBooks
AFTER INSERT ON BooKLoan 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
   UPDATE Book SET noOfLoan=noOfLoans + 1  
   WHERE Bookloan.bookTitle= :new.bookTitle;
END;
/
```

(adding one to the noOfLoans column for a book title in table Book, after each time that book title is entered into a new loan row in table BookLoan)

Can anyone help me to the solution please ?

Comment: Do not understand,  Please clarify.

Comment: You have a trigger. You cannot make it work. How do you try to make it work? What happens afterwards?

Comment: What is the erro? What do you want to do and what do you have as results?

Comment: Tables are already created, everytime a row is added to the table bookLoan, NoOfLoans column in another table must update by one.

Comment: the errors just says, trigger created with compilation errors

Comment: SO SHOW US THE COMPILATION ERRORS!

Answer (score 1):

Making some wild assumptions here that you want to increment `Book.noOfLoans` every time an associated `BookLoan` record is inserted, There are at least 2 issues in your code:

```
UPDATE Book 
   SET noOfLoan=noOfLoan + 1  
   WHERE Book.bookTitle = :new.bookTitle;
```

1. noOfLoan or noOfLoans but not both
2. Since the trigger is on Bookloan, and it seems you want to update `Book`, you'll need to filter on `Book.bookTitle`, not `Bookloan` (since the `new` pseudo row is already a `Bookloan` row)